# postfix, spam assassin, swiftmailer

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

Linux webserver, running a local postfix mail server, PHP web systems on apache. Postfix is configured to pass emails to spampd for spam checking but local networks are exempted:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       20      smtpd
-o smtpd_proxy_filter=127.0.0.1:10025
-o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=10 127.0.0.1:10026 inet n  -       n       -        -      smtpd
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

This works for all our websystems except the newest, which is running Yii2 and Swiftmailer.  Emails from this system are being passed to spampd unnecessarily and this is slowing response times dramatically.

Here is a typical mail log showing the problem:

```
Sep 17 10:37:33 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtpd[28970]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 17 10:37:33 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtpd[28990]: NOQUEUE: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 17 10:37:33 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtpd[28970]: E3526409A9: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 17 10:37:33 ip-172-31-12-147 spampd[23514]: processing message <c2ff05d7cabef914ac2fce75430a8257@alpinebookings.cbdweb.net> for <***@cbdweb.net>
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 spampd[23514]: clean message <c2ff05d7cabef914ac2fce75430a8257@alpinebookings.cbdweb.net> (-102.90/5.00) from <***@cbdweb.net> for <***@cbdweb.net> in 5.14s, 1250 bytes.
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/cleanup[28971]: E3526409A9: message-id=<c2ff05d7cabef914ac2fce75430a8257@alpinebookings.cbdweb.net>
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/qmgr[20013]: E3526409A9: from=<***@cbdweb.net>, size=1753, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtpd[28990]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E3526409A9; from=<***@cbdweb.net> to=<***@cbdweb.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<alpinebookings.cbdweb.net>
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtpd[28970]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtpd[28990]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=2 rcpt=2 data=2 quit=1 commands=8
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtp[28983]: E3526409A9: to=<***@cbdweb.net>, relay=ip-172-31-11-15.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal[172.31.11.15]:25, delay=5.2, delays=5.2/0/0.01/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 17 10:37:39 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/qmgr[20013]: E3526409A9: removed
```

Compare to email sent by a wordpress site on the same server:

```
Sep 17 11:00:04 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/pickup[27803]: 33917409AA: uid=33 from=<apache>
Sep 17 11:00:04 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/cleanup[30456]: 33917409AA: message-id=<99bd4d40cc970cae10758aed89bf60d4@patscherkofel.com.au>
Sep 17 11:00:04 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/qmgr[20013]: 33917409AA: from=<***@cbdweb.net>, size=847, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 17 11:00:24 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/smtp[30458]: 33917409AA: to=<***@***.com>, relay=mx1.***.com.au[103.240.135.130]:25, delay=20, delays=0.05/0/0.08/20, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as 2F3701100075)
Sep 17 11:00:24 ip-172-31-12-147 postfix/qmgr[20013]: 33917409AA: removed
```

The Yii2 configuration of the mailer is:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => $params['level'] === 'DEV' ? '***.cbdweb.net' : '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '25'
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Your WordPress installation is dropping mail directly into the local mail spool by calling the sendmail command. But your swiftmailer code is connecting via SMTP (over the network). It could be configured to also use sendmail as its transport; see [so] for help on writing the necessary PHP code to do that. There is nothing in your Postfix configuration that exempts this mail from being passed to SpamAssassin, and it's not clear why you think that there is. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Thanks your answer is spot on.  If you would like to make it the answer I will mark it as correct.
The Yii2 configuration to use is 
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                    'class' => 'Swift_SendmailTransport'
                ]
            )
        ],
This uses a default value for the sendmail command which worked for me on Ubuntu, I suspect this is equivalent to 'command'=>'/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs' but Yii2 doesn't provide any documentation on this.

Comment: I'll ask a separate question on how to stop postfix from sending mail to spampd when the connecting server is localhost. I'd like to compare this config with using sendmail directly, because at the moment bounces aren't going to the return-path address, they are going to the webserver admin. I wonder if using SMTP would fix this.

Comment: Follow up question is at https://serverfault.com/questions/984531/how-to-stop-postfix-from-forwarding-mail-to-spampd-when-connection-is-from-local

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sendmail, it is possible to avoid the milter (mail filter) problem by using the SMTP port that postfix listens on for output from the milter.  This is fully explained in my answer to the follow-up question at [How to stop postfix from forwarding mail to spampd when connection is from localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/984531/how-to-stop-postfix-from-forwarding-mail-to-spampd-when-connection-is-from-local)